Justification of the initial steps of the proof of the Extreme Value Theorem
In Wade's the Extreme Value Theorem is stated as follows.
If $I$ is a closed, bounded interval and $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $I$, then $f$ is bounded on $I$. Moreover, if
\begin{equation*}
    M = \sup \limits_{x \in I} f(x)~~~\text{and}~~~m = \inf \limits_{x \in I} f(x),
\end{equation*}
then there exists points $x_m,~ x_M \in I$ such that
$$f(x_M)=M~~~\text{and}~~~f(x_m)=m~.$$
The proof starts with the method of contradiction which I understand and the existence of a convergent subsequence. What I don't understand is the existence of the sequence $\{ x_n \}$. Any help in understanding this is much appreciated.

Suppose first that $f$ is not bounded on $I$. Then there exist $x_n \in I$ such that
$$|f(x_n)|>n,~~~ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ $$
Since $I$ is bounded, we know (by the \textbf{Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem}) that $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence, say $x_{n_k} \to a$ as $k \to \infty$.

If it's not bounded, then it exceeds every integer, so find a point that makes it exceed $n$.

I can't tell what sequence might be involved.  $m$ and $M$ are real numbers; $x_m$   and $x_M$ are points in the interval $I$ where the infimum and the supremum of $f$ are achieved.

@WillJagy, I'm just wondering how the sequence $x_n$ is existed.

The series $x_n$ exists by the definition of non-boundedness. You probably defined $f$ is bounded on $I$ to mean:
$$ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}~~\forall x\in I~~ |f(x)|\leq n. $$
If $f$ is not bounded on $I$, then the negation of that statement is true, which is exactly the following statement:
$$ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}~~~ \exists x_n \in I : |f(x_n)|>n . $$
This gives rise to the series $\{x_n\}$.
